# How to copy PHP files from windows to ubuntu?

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, copy

How to copy PHP files from windows to ubuntu without causing problems ?(because of \r and \n) as when enter code here I have copied them directly , and trying to browse the files , nothing response on ubuntu !

### The question is:

why when I am copying files from windows to ubuntu and trying to browse the php files , I don't get any result in the page despite it shows result when browsing them on windows ?!

### Edit :

now I have more information after using

```
// Enable error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_error', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

I got this error ..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.' in /var/www/yajoop/facebook/src/base_facebook.php:19 ..
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the question? Please clarify.

Comment: @adham: If you have `\r\n` or `\n`, both would be executed by PHP on ubuntu, so that is *not* the cause of your problem.

Comment: You can not set `ini_set('display_startup_error', 1);` inside of a script. It needs to be set in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problems are due to differences of EOL (End Of Line) characters between different operating systems.

Instead, check your PHP error log or enable ["display_startup_errors"](http://php.net/display_startup_errors).

The PHP error log file is usually located at:
`/var/www/apache2/error.log`

To see the errors directly in the web page, add the follow code to the top of your PHP file.

```
// Enable error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_error', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```